# PayPal purchase or donate form url using GET

Tags: url, paypal, get

Is there a way to open PayPal's _xclick purchase/donate url by filling the parameters using a GET request? The reason is I'm trying to open the PayPal page up in an iframe inside a PhoneGap app.

Normally I'd use the form below.

I've scoured the web, but have been unable to find anything (making me think it doesn't exist)  but wanted to check it out with everyone here.

Presumably it would be something like:

https: www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=info@example.org&tax=0 ... etc, etc..

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    <form id="paypal" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@example.org">
        <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
        <input type="submit" value="$5" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Duh. Just putting as get string works fine.

```
https: www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=info@example.org&tax=0&item_name=donation&currency_code=USD&amount=5.00
```

Nope. It crashes with -999 error. It's a common problem loading PayPal into a uiwebview apparently.